# Javascript name surname validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, validation

Hey guys ı want to validate name,surname etc in javascript.

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z ]{1,20}$/;
```

When I typed harun(which is obviously true) but it gives false,When ı typed harun12 it gives false too.Can anyone tell me what am ı doing wrong with this code?

function check() {

```
            var name = document.getElementById('<%= txt2.ClientID%>');
            var surname = document.getElementById('<%= txt3.ClientID%>');

            var textregex = /^[A-Za-z ]{1,20}$/;
            alert(textregex.test("harun"));

            if ((name.value == '') || (textregex.test(name) == false) ) {
                $("#name_error").dialog("open");
                $("#txt2").val('');

            }
            if ((surname.value == '') || (textregex.test(surname) == false){
                $("#surname_error").dialog("open");
                $("#txt3").val('');

            }


        }

    });
```

```
        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell>Name:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt2" />
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow3" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell>Surname:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server"/>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt3" />
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

Comment: `regex.test('harun')` returns `true` when I tried.

Comment: Do you write your name in the same way as `"harun"` or there are any other non-Latin characters?

Comment: Please consider [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: actually this is the asp code where ı use <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" /> and where ı get value var name = document.getElementById('<%= name.ClientID%>');  after that ı controlled with var textregex = /^[A-Za-z ]{1,20}$/;
                alert(textregex.test(name));

Comment: 12 or other number dont be accepted by your regex so it's normal

Comment: `alert(textregex.test(name.value));` , use `name.value` instead of `name`

Comment: please edit your post and  show your full source code.

Comment: François Toolte-O'Willis 3rd weeps at this.

Comment: yeah ı just checked alert(textregex.test("harun")); gives true. I think the problem is the part with var name = document.getElementById('<%= name.ClientID%>');

Comment: @harunyılmaz : try `alert(textregex.test(name.value));`

Comment: Could you edit your question to contain all the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment `name` refers to dom object not it's value so use

```
alert(textregex.test(name.value)); 
//                       --^--
```

or

```
var name = document.getElementById('<%= name.ClientID%>').value;
//                                                        --^--
```

**Update**

```
if ((name.value == '') || (textregex.test(name.value) == false)) {
  //                                           --^--
  $("#name_error").dialog("open");
  $("#txt2").val('');
}
if ((surname.value == '') || (textregex.test(surname.value) == false)) {
  //                                                 --^--
  $("#surname_error").dialog("open");
  $("#txt3").val('');
}
```

Comment: thanks man ı have been working all day to find this. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z1-9]{1,20}$/;
regex.test('text');//True
regex.test('text123');//True
```

What you are wrong, it is that the validation is only sure that you have alphabetic characters, so false damage when it contains numbers.

If you want to allow bank space uses like this:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z1-9\s]{1,20}$/;
regex.test('text123 ');//True
regex.test('text 123');//True
regex.test('text test2');//True
```